# Parsing ID from List of Strings with Regex

Tags: python, regex

If you have a list of strings:

```
Z100 = [
    '[ship, \'house\', "boat": 65, "price":10000, "car_id":"128bhsdfb03-2389-1379be8", "age":15]',
    '[ ]',
    '[shoe, 8000, "car_id":"asdlp-2394397-2njn84-kncbka", \'store\', "boat": 20, "price":4050, "age":43]'
]
```

How do you use a regex do get the following list?

```
car_id = ['128bhsdfb03-2389-1379be8', '', 'asdlp-2394397-2njn84-kncbka']
```

I tried using the following code, but it did not work:

```
new_results = []

for item in car_id:
    new_list = re.search(r"car_id[^\d]*?(\d+)", item)
if new_list:
    new_results.append(str(item.group(1)))
```

Comment: Can you check your input list to make sure it's formatted correctly? And I don't see the word `batch_id` anywhere in your input list...

Comment: There are too many `'` single quotes in the string you provided, please double check it.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a list of lists of string, though? The strings in your post seem like they really should be a list of its own. It will be much easier to manage it once you convert to that format.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall`:

```
import re

Z100 = [ '[ship, "house", "boat": 65, "price":10000, "car_id":"128bhsdfb03-2389-1379be8", "age":15]', '[ ]', '[shoe, 8000, "car_id":"asdlp-2394397-2njn84-kncbka", "store", "boat": 20, "price":4050, "age":43]' ] 

lst = []
for x in Z100:
    v = re.findall(r'"car_id":"(.*?)"', x)  # Or re.findall(r'"car_id":"([^"]+)', x)
    if v:
        lst.extend(v)
    else:
        lst.extend(' ')

print(lst)
# ['128bhsdfb03-2389-1379be8', ' ', 'asdlp-2394397-2njn84-kncbka']
```

Comment: Consider using `"car_id":"([^"]+)"` as a pattern instead, negated character sets are more efficient than `.*?`. The lookahead is also redundant here.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: Seems better than mine. Thanks for your point.